# Question about the definition of finitely generated module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Definition: A module $M$ over a commutative ring $R$ is said to be finitely generated by $m_1,\dots,m_n \in M$ if for any $m \in M$, there exist $r_1,\dots, r_n \in R$ such that $m = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i m_i$.

My question is that does the above definition imply $$M = \sum_{i=1}^n R m_i,$$ where $R m_i:= \{m \mid m = r m_i, r\in R\}?$

The definition in the first paragraph only states the exists of $r_i$ for a given $m$, but it seems not to exclude the situation where there may exist $r_1,\dots,r_n \in R$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n r m_i$ is not in $M$. Is there a proof needed for the property under question? Or is the property under question self-evident from the definition?

If the property does not hold, do I need to impose additional conditions on the $R$-module $M$? For example, by restricting it to be a free module or by restricting $R$ to be a principal ideal domain?

Comment: Yes, thats the definition

Comment: On one hand you seem to assume a left module, but then later on it's a right module.  Does this matter?

Comment: Unless $R$ is commutative, you should have $M = \sum_{i=1}^n Rm_i$. By the way, what you wrote, means precisely that $m_i$ are generators of $M$. Here the sum is taken as submodules of $M$, so it doesn't have to be a direct sum. In general it won't be, say if the module $M$ isn't free.

Comment: Please don't title posts "question about <generic thing>".  For one thing, it does absolutely nothing to distinguish your question from every other question on the topic. For another thing _every_ post is a question of some sort, so bothering to put "question" in the title is simply silly.  A good title in this case is simply "Does a finitely generated module look like $M = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i R,$?" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a left $R$ module $M$ generated by $m_1,\ldots, m_n$, it is true that $\sum_{i=1}^n Rm_i=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n r_i m_i\mid r_i\in R\right\}$, if that's what you're asking. As far as I know, that's the definition everyone is given.

In general it won't make sense to put elements of $r$ on the right of elements of $m$ since no such operation was defined.  But if, say, $R$ is commutative, then you *could* consider it as a left and right module and move the ring elements to either side.

Typically though people are going to pick one side and stick with it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Sorry for the confusion, and I have edited it to make the ring commutative. It seems that the definition I am using is slightly different., as it does not explicitly state that any $r_1,\dots, r_n \in R$ results into a $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i m_i$ that is in $M$. The same definition is also used on Wikipedia.

Comment: @ShiJames Well, no matter what $r$ you pick, $rm_i$ has to be in $M$ (since $m_i$ is) so $Rm_i$ is clearly a subset of $M$. And so are the finite sums of all such sets. So the full sum is contained in $M$.  On the other hand, your definition of "finite set of generators $m_1,\ldots, m_n$ says that there is nothing more, that the two are equal.

Comment: That answers my question! Thanks!